# Skrill Payment gateway displays only "Skrill Digital Wallet" payment option

Tags: html, payment-gateway, payment

I was trying to integrate the skrill payment gateway to my website. I used the below HTML code

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="https://www.moneybookers.com/app/payment.pl" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="pay_to_email" value="xxx@xxx.com"/>

<input type="hidden" name="language" value="EN"/>
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="60"/>
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="USD"/>
<input type="hidden" name="detail1_description" value="YourApp"/>
<input type="submit" value="Pay!"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

However it is showing only the "Skrill Wallet" payment method. `yohan@theacetechnologies.com` is not a test account, it is my real account. And I am from Sri Lanka.

Can you help me to find what is going on here?

Comment: Seeing as there is no skrill tag yet, I don't think there are many users who will have an expert knowledge of the Skrill payment gateway. This question may be better suited to Skrill's tech support / bug tracker. But I could be wrong.

Comment: @TinyGiant: Yeah. You know any good payment service?

Comment: I haven't used it yet myself but the next one I'm going to be implementing will be [stripe](https://stripe.com/). But I don't know if there is much of a following for that here either.

Answer (score 0):

Way back when Skrill was Moneybookers our integration used...

```
<input type='hidden' name='hide_login' value='1'>
<input type='hidden' name="payment_methods" value="ACC">
```

The alternate option was...

```
<input type='hidden' name='hide_login' value='0'>
<input type='hidden' name="payment_methods" value="WLT">
```

Hope this helps.